# Analog and digital grounds on a DAC

Tags: pcb-design, dac, ground-plane

I've read at several places ([1](http://www.analog.com/library/analogdialogue/archives/46-06/staying_well_grounded.html),[2](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX504-MAX515.pdf)) that ICs such as DACs have both analog and digital ground pins, both should be tied to AGND at the chip.

However, the specific part I'm planning to use ([MAX5104](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX5104.pdf)) does not claim so in the datasheet, showing instead that the DGND pin be connected to the board's digital ground plane. Why exactly is that?

Comment: what will happen if the analog side of DAC has its own dedicated floating power supply. Is it still necessary to connect floating ground to digital ground? I would guess not. Any comments?

Answer (score 2):

In general, your analog signals should stay in the analog section of the board and your digital signals should stay in the digital section of the board. You should have separate ground planes for each. However, these ground planes must connect to provide a consistent reference point to both sections.

Ideally, the analog sections and the digital sections should connect at a single point. The "star" connection mentioned in your links and by MoJo. Though sometimes this is not possible. But basically what you want is a small "bridge" to connect the two sections. Any signals that must cross between the sections should be routed over this bridge.

The reason for doing this is to prevent or minimize any noise from switching signals on the digital section from disturbing or corrupting any analog signals that you are trying to generate or measure. The split prevents digital currents from flowing into the analog ground plane. While the "bridge" connects the two ground planes so the ground reference is at a consistent level in both sections.

A good reference for why and how to ground mixed signal systems is Henry Ott's [Grounding of Mixed Signal PCBs](https://web.archive.org/web/20220104100355/http://www.hottconsultants.com/techtips/split-gnd-plane.html). Some diagrams from that page will help to explain some best practices:

[image: Signal traces crossing a split ground plane]
[image: Separate analog & digital gnd plane regions]

As for the power supplies, they can come from the same source. Usually the bypass capacitors specified in the datasheets are sufficient to decouple the power between the sections. However, if the noise on the board is particularly bad, sometimes additional filter circuitry is necessary. For instance the one seen [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/scaa048/scaa048.pdf):

[image: Power supply filter circuit]

Or, you could have a separate regulator to provide clean, stable power to any of your analog devices. This will most likely provide the best accuracy but at extra expense, board area, and circuit complexity.

Comment: What about power supplies? I have, for instance, 5V switching regulator powering a DAC (and other A/D ICs like opamps) and Shift Registers/H-Bridge ICs. Do I need two separate 5V supplies or can it be shared, as long as the rails and the ground planes are properly separated?

Comment: @joaocandre Updated to address your comment.

Comment: Ott's guide is a very interesting read. However what if I was lookinng to create a separate power ground?

Comment: @joaocandre The same principle applies. You can have as many sections as you want but they all need to connect through "bridges" or "stars". For example, look at the diagram above labeled "Seperate Analog & Digital Gnd. Plan Regions". Instead of "Analog 3" you could just as easily place your power supply there and call it "Power 1". That would keep the noise from your switching regulator confined to that section so it wouldn't interfere with your digital or analog sections. But the digital and analog sections still have to have the same reference point, hence the narrow connection.

Comment: My issue is with ICs I'd be placing on the 'border'. I have ICs that require Analog and Power ground, and ICs that require Analog and Digital grounds. Thus I would somehow need to create those narrow connections between all of them, whcih I means I won't get a single connection out of each plane.

Comment: @joaocandre I'm not sure I understand the problem. The analog pins are placed over the analog planes, the digital pins are placed over the digital planes, and the power pins are placed over the power planes. You then route channel voids in the copper to separate the sections as best you can. Proper placing and routing may require some creative geometry. Maybe if you can add a sample of your routing with the chips you plan to use to your question I could better understand what the problem is.

Comment: It all comes down to creative geometry alright. My worry is however with the possibily of the digital part having two escape routes (to analog and power planes), but I've realised the same happens with Ott's sugestion, so there shouldn't be any problem

Comment: @joaocandre Exactly. Choose a "main plane" and connect everything to that. Like this: `digital`=>`analog`, `digital`=>`power` Whatever you do, don't create a loop. Don't connect them like this: `digital`=>`analog`=>`power`=>`digital` Ground loops cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: My current issue is that the 'main' plane would have to be the analog one. I need at least a `power=>analog` and a `digital=>analog` border to place my ICs. However, would that somehow increase the noise sources in the analog plane?

Comment: @joaocandre Not if you're careful with your placement. Each section should be like an island with a small bridge to your mainland/main plane. When you do your placement, try to keep the noisy stuff (the switching power supply, digital PWMs, etc.) as far from the bridges as possible. That should allow the noisy ground currents to dissipate over the appropriate ground section before crossing the bridge because the plane should be low impedance when compared to the bridge which should be a higher impedance.

Comment: Would a `power->analog1`, `power->digital`, and `digital->analog2` configuration be apropriate? What are those loops I should avoid?

Comment: @joaocandre That could work. You just can't connect `analog1->analog2` or `power->analog2`. `analog2` will need to get its power from `digital`. Through a separate regulator would be best. The regulator should be grounded as close to the bridge as possible.

Comment: Just one more small remark. In each of those analog mini-planes shown in Ott's figure above, the planes are connected on both sides of the IC. Won't this create the possibility of a ground loop?

Comment: @joaocandre If there were two bridges on either side of the IC, then yes, there would be a ground loop. But that's not what the picture is showing. It is one bridge that goes completely under the IC. The IC is then grounded using very small traces and vias to the ground plane on another layer.

Comment: However with some small and quad packages, with a pad on the underside (albeit to ground), becomes next to impossible to have a continuous large bridge between zones. I guess in that case one should have as many vias as possible to a layer where the bridge is more homogeneous?

Comment: @joaocandre If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you are trying to route your ground and signals on the same layer and snake your ground plane between your pins and signals underneath the chip. The ground plane should be it's own separate layer. Everything should connect to it using vias. The number of vias used for ground pads under chips is determined by the thermal dissipation needed.

Comment: I only have two sides to my PCB, and routing every signal on the same layer is impossible, which is why I'm also using the opposite side to partially route some signals, while having identical groud plane geomtries on both sides. Also, since I have passive componentes on the same side of the ICs, I need the ground as well.

Comment: @joaocandre Take a look at NXP's [AN10897](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/an10897.pdf) Almost all of Section 3 would be applicable to your problem. But pay special attention to Sections 3.1.3 in which they discuss using ground grids instead of ground planes in a two layer board and 3.1.4.9 where they discuss routing power and ground traces in parallel when using a grid.

Comment: Why certainly relevant and an interesting read, it failed to answer my main doubt: how to route traces through the bridge between planes, when an IC is already "blocking".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15808/discussion-between-embedded-kyle-and-joaocandre).

Answer (score 0):

The grounds need to be connected together, the question is where do you connect them. If you use the same ground plane for both the IC will work, but you will get digital switching noise on the analogue signals. The most common solution is to use a separate ground plane for analogue and digital, with them connected together at a "star" point very close to the power supply connector. That way any noise from the digital side will be isolated from the analogue side as current flows back to the power supply connector, not past the analogue ground pins.

Comment: I am aware of that, the issue is where do I connect them. MAX504's datasheet suggests is to be at the IC, in addition to a connection at the power supply, but MAX5104 does not provide any information about that...