# Does separating DGND and AGND with two different layers for each make any sense?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, analog, pcb-layers, ground-plane

In my [last question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/660953/91862) I found out that having two different layers for Ground and Analog Ground may induce capacitive coupling. Now I want to ask more generally if the idea I had is worse than connecting DGND and AGND on the same plane. May PCB stack-up is currently as follows:

> Signal, DGND, AGND, Signal

My PCB looks like this:

[image]

So there is an ESP32-S3 (bottom right), MAX6675 temperature sensor (top right), camera interface (SCCB) working at 20 MHz (top mid), Li-po charging circuitry (top left), Li-po protection circuitry (top left), 3.3 V power supply (left mid), 1.5 V and 2.8 V power supplies (left of cam connector) and an ADC (ADS1110) above the battery connector.

To the AGND plane is only connected the AGND Pin of the 3.3 V power supply and the AGND pin of the camera.

If it is a bad idea, how can I make it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *My PCB Stackup is currently as follows:*
>
> *Signal, DGND, AGND, Signal*

Put DGND and AGND on the same layer to avoid the problem that you mentioned (capacitive coupling) and, to keep both GNDs close below the components they are acting as a GND-plane for.

You just need to figure out how and where you connect the AGND and DGND planes (hint a single point connection at the junction of some type of analogue to digital conversion I.C. is normally recommended).

Comment: Okay but I have to have 4 layers, because you can only choose from 2 or 4. So should I switch to Signal - GND - GND - Signal or GND - Signal - Signal -GND? Or does it make sense to transform the Analog Plane into a power plane? (I have 1.5V, 2.8V, 3.3V power supplies, can I all put them in that power plane?

Comment: I always have signal on the outer layers because, if I screw up, I can fix with track cuts. The DC stuff might conveniently go on the middle plane furthest from the component side.

Comment: @CemPamirBana are we done here now?